# Why is the name of the MAKEDEV script spelled in all caps?

Tags: filenames, devices, history

While usually all Linux commands are spelled in lowercase, that's not the case of the [`MAKEDEV`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/makedev) script, which is in uppercase. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: perhaps so no one would ever run it accidentally ?

Answer (score 10):

It is likely that Linux borrowed this script from a pre-existing Unix.

The earliest version of this script that I've been able to track down is called [`/dev/MAKE` on BSD 4](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4-Snapshot-Development/dev/MAKE), which I believe is from around 1980. It is obviously named that way because it makes the device files. The upper-casing of the name may have been to distinguish it from the device files themselves, but that's speculating.

Before that, the device files seems to have been made with an actual Makefile,
 as in [Bell Labs Research V7 snapshot (1979)](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/dev/makefile), and before that I'm not sure the `/dev` hierarchy existed at all.

With BSD 4.1 (1982), this script [was still called `/dev/MAKE`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/BSD-4_1_snap-Snapshot-Development/dev/MAKE), but in BSD 4.1c_2 (1983) [there seems to have existed a `/dev/MAKEDEV.local` script](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/tree/BSD-4_1c_2-Snapshot-Development/dev) of some description. It is not clear whether there ever was a `/dev/MAKEDEV` script alongside it.

In the BSD 4.4 Lite2 release (1995 according to the repository, but the SCCS timestamp in the file itself says `8.1 (Berkeley) 6/9/93`) we can see the script with its final name [`/dev/MAKEDEV`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/tree/BSD-Release/dev) along with a couple of system-specific `MAKEDEV` scripts. By this time the script already exists with the same name on the Linux side ([as mentioned by Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356130/116858)).

Comment: I wondered if it came from somewhere else, I didn’t think to look at the BSDs, or in unix-history for that matter!

Comment: Just a quibble on your edit: the attributions to Bill Joy and Ken Thompson are the defaults respectively for BSD 4 and V7, and don’t correspond to hard-and-fast information (see [these files](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-make/tree/master/src/author-path) for details). Also the 4.1c_2 `MAKEDEV.local` is empty (although the important part is its name).

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks Stephen! Yes, the file is empty, but it exists. I'm assuming that there are a lot of other files that are either empty or non-existent for various reasons (licences?).

Comment: @StephenKitt The exact dates are also a bit wobbly it seems.

Comment: Probably just lost in the mists of time (or, if it was intended for local changes, taken from a system with no changes)...

Comment: Yes, the dates don’t necessarily match. The dates in revision control headers inside the files themselves give an idea of how old they are. Diomidis Spinellis has written quite a bit about how the repository is put together, it makes for interesting reading (well, for people interested in the history of all this stuff!). The TUHS mailing list also has quite a bit of info.

Comment: It's probably uppercase to make it stand out in directory listings, like `README` and `Makefile`.

Comment: `MAKEDEV` is documented in BSD 4.2 (1983) manual pages and possibly appeared in a late 4.1 release as you found. I have no reference to back that idea but I always thought the uppercase name was chosen because it makes the script appear first when running the `ls` command in `/dev`.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can determine, this is the history of `MAKEDEV` on Linux:

- in March 1992, Jim Winstead added an installation helper in [version 0.95a](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/Linux.old/docs/CHANGES-0.95a) of his root diskette, called `/INSTALL/mkdev`;
- in July 1992, this became `/dev/MAKEDEV` in [version 0.96](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/Linux.old/docs/CHANGES-0.96) of the root diskette;
- by December 1993, Nick Holloway has expanded on this in a dedicated [MAKEDEV project](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.os.linux.announce/hktgeHrWcUQ/discussion) (version 1.2 appears to be the first publicly-released version).

So the key to the script’s name is the switch from `/INSTALL/mkdev` to `/dev/MAKEDEV`. I’d guess that it was upper-cased to avoid any potential confusion and namespace clashes with device node names, since they (always?) start with a lower-case letter. This was long before the FHS, when binaries lived in various places (including `/etc`), so having a device node creation script in `/dev` was sensible enough.

Comment: Ah, we agree on the possible reason for the upper-casing of the filename. Yes, device nodes have always been lowercase. In fact, there is very few _old_ files with _any_ uppercase letters in them, and when there are uppercase letters it's mostly for attention: `READ_ME`, etc.  Or possibly for sorting in file listings.

Comment: `MAKEDEV` predates Linux by almost a decade.

Comment: Until about 2010ish, starting a file's name with an uppercase ASCII letter would cause it to be sorted to the beginning of a directory listing.  This is heavily used in the conventions for source code "releases": README, Makefile, COPYING, ChangeLog, etc. are all supposed to be at the beginning of the listing, with the actual code (in files beginning with lowercase letters) next.  Sadly, this convention got broken when the C library maintainers decided that most people probably want case-insensitive sorting out of strcoll(). They're not _wrong_, but ...