# Why can't I find MAKEDEV in the /dev folder?

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, udev

I'm currently exploring the directory tree on Linux Mint while supporting it by a book that I bought. Well, the book specifically said that:

> The `/dev` directory contains the special device files for all the devices. The device files are created during installation, and later with the `/dev/MAKEDEV` script. The `/dev/MAKEDEV.local` is a script written by the system administrator that creates local-only device files or links (...)

I can't find that script, am I supposed to find it or is it generated upon installation of a new device?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your book was correct when it was written, but it is now obsolete. `MAKEDEV` used to be a script in `/dev`, potentially supplemented by a local `MAKEDEV.local` written by the system administrator; nowadays, if it exists, it’s more likely to live in `/sbin`.

Many current Linux systems don’t have a `MAKEDEV` at all, they rely on the kernel and `udev` to populate device nodes as necessary.

See [Why is the name of the MAKEDEV script spelled in all caps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356000/86440) for more on the history of `MAKEDEV`.

Answer (score 3):

As per @StephenKitt's comment, the book must be outdated; see [Why is the name of the MAKEDEV script spelled in all caps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356000/86440) .

Actually `MAKEDEV` is in `/sbin/`.  [From the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/makedev):

```
Name

MAKEDEV - create devices

Synopsis

/sbin/MAKEDEV -V
/sbin/MAKEDEV [ -d directory ] [ -D directory ] [ -c configdir ] [ -m maxdevices ] [-a] [-n] [-v] [-i] [-M] [-S] [-u] [-x] " device ..."

Description

MAKEDEV is a program that will create the devices in /dev used to interface
with drivers in the kernel.

Note that programs giving the error ''ENOENT: No such file or directory''
normally means that the device file is missing, whereas ''ENODEV: No such
device'' normally means the kernel does not have the driver configured or loaded.
```

Comment: Well thank you, i’m going to check that . I assumed That it was located under /dev because of the Book. Yeah, i’m going to find another book. Thank you!

Comment: The book was correct when it was written: `/dev/MAKEDEV` and `/dev/MAKEDEV.local` were used in the past, a long long time ago...

Comment: See [Why is the name of the MAKEDEV script spelled in all caps?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356000/86440) for more on this.

Comment: @StephenKitt thank you for the info . I understand it now !

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks, I did not know that. Corrected my answer.